# Story identification: person gets super powers from chocolate

Tags: story-identification, food, powers

I must have seen this in passing about a decade ago. All I remember was the hero got their powers (possibly accidentally) from ingesting chocolate (I *think* it was just ordinary chocolate, not a special super powered formula).  It's been so long I can't even recall if it was a cartoon, comic or written story.

And no, it's not *The Secret World of Alex Mack,*  where the young heroine would get different abilities from eating various foods, like super strength from curry rice. Nor is it that super-powered alien from *Ben 10* who got *poisoned* from eating chocolate.

Does anyone have *Any* idea what this might be?

Comment: Checking the "[Power-Up Food](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PowerUpFood)" TV Tropes page and searching for "chocolate" yielded no results, sadly.

Comment: No dice on the [Superpower wiki](https://powerlisting.fandom.com/wiki/Chocolate_Empowerment) either:

Comment: If it was a chocolate drink then maybe Fatman, the human flying saucer?  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fatman_the_Human_Flying_Saucer

Comment: @DannyMcG Just finished reading it. Thank you. Similar, but no, not what I remember.

Comment: Reading the title -- getting (super)powers from eating chocolate -- this is science fiction?  I thought it was real life...

Comment: @Basya LOL... I'm sorry, i thought it being a story in sci-fi or comics was implied. You make a good point, though; it could be mistaken if not outright said.

Comment: My comment was not intended to be serious or critical in any way; just a joke from a chocolate lover...

Comment: @Basya I was just being facetious too, buddy....